# Why doesn't isformula() work on Excel 2011 for OS X?

Tags: macos, microsoft-excel

Supposedly, Excel has isformula(), but all it ever gives me is #NAME?  For me, isformula() is not even listed in Excel as a valid function at all!  Nor is there any mention of it in the help whatsoever.

Anyone have any idea how I can get this simple function to work on Excel 2011 OS X?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no Excel 2013 for the Mac, as far as I am aware. The most current version is still 2011. If you have an Office 365 license that allows installing Office on the Mac, you won't get 2013 but 2011 on the Mac.

The ISFORMULA() function is new to Excel 2013 and does not exist in Excel 2011 for Mac.

But you can easily write it yourself in VBA. The following code is quoted from OZGrid.com
http://www.ozgrid.com/VBA/ExcelIsFormula.htm

> This UDF will return TRUE if the referenced cell houses an Excel
>   formula
>
> The Code

```
Function IsFormula(Check_Cell As Range)
   IsFormula = Check_Cell.HasFormula
End Function
```

> To use this UDF push Alt+F11 and go Insert>Module and
>   paste in the code. Push Alt+Q and save. The Function will appear under
>   "User Defined" in the Paste Function dialog box (Shift+F3). Use the
>   Function in any cell as shown below.
>
> =IsFormula(A1) This will return TRUE if A1 houses a formula. It is very useful when used with Conditional Formatting as you can
>   dynamically color all formulae cells.

Comment: Oh geez, brain fart... you are correct, it's 2011 for Mac.  Will amend the question...

Comment: I added some more to the answer.

Comment: Aha... I was wondering if perhaps 2011 just plain didn't have it.  I managed to make do without it this time, but this is good to know for future reference.  Will accept your answer... thanks!

Comment: The amount of time it took to find this...  Also:  Thanks for the explicit key strokes to add it to the file.  One note:  You need to save as an xlsm instead of xlsx file.